# Nhibernate 3.0: problems with Future<> and Restrictions on a join table

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I can't figure out what the problem with nHibernate.
My domain is quite simple. Since most of my data is show in a paginated grid (jqGrid) I need to use **Future<>** to get the total number of rows.
If I run this chunk of code here it works properly:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteriaCount = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();

var TotalRecords = FiltersCriteriaCount
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
    .FutureValue<Int32>();

var sResult = FiltersCriteria
    .CreateAlias("Company", "Company")
    .CreateAlias("PlanType", "PlanType")
    .CreateAlias("OperationsManager", "OperationsManager")
    .CreateAlias("Schedules", "Schedules", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .SetFirstResult(0)
    .SetMaxResults(100)
    .Future<Domain.Reminder>()
    .ToList<Domain.Reminder>();
```

but if I add a restriction I get an exception `could not resolve property: Schedules.Notes of: BpReminders.Domain.Reminder`:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteriaCount = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();

FiltersCriteriaCount.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Schedules.Notes", ""));
FiltersCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Schedules.Notes", ""));

var TotalRecords = FiltersCriteriaCount
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
    .FutureValue<Int32>();

var sResult = FiltersCriteria
    .CreateAlias("Company", "Company")
    .CreateAlias("PlanType", "PlanType")
    .CreateAlias("OperationsManager", "OperationsManager")
    .CreateAlias("Schedules", "Schedules", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .SetFirstResult(0)
    .SetMaxResults(100)
    .Future<Domain.Reminder>()
    .ToList<Domain.Reminder>();
```

If I get rid of Future<> and trasform my code like this everything works fine:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();
FiltersCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Schedules.Notes", ""));

var sResult = FiltersCriteria
    .CreateAlias("Company", "Company")
    .CreateAlias("PlanType", "PlanType")
    .CreateAlias("OperationsManager", "OperationsManager")
    .CreateAlias("Schedules", "Schedules", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .SetFirstResult(0)
    .SetMaxResults(100)
    .List<Domain.Reminder>();
```

I can't find the reason for that.
Any help would be really really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, try this:

```
var TotalRecords = FiltersCriteriaCount
    .CreateAlias("Schedules", "Schedules", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
    .FutureValue<Int32>();
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. I should have thought about that :-s Silly mistake. Great.